# Use Java Streams to get max value for combination of parameters

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm looking to transition this code to use Streams.

```java
public ResultObject getBestObjectWithParameters() {
    int maxParameterValue = 10;
    double bestValue = 0.0;
    ResultObject bestObject = null;
    for (int a = 0; a < maxParameterValue; a++) {
      for (int b = 0; b < maxParameterValue; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < maxParameterValue; c++) {
          ResultObject o = runCalculation(a, b, c);
          if (o.getValue() > bestValue) {
            bestValue = getValue;
            bestObject = o;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return bestObject;
  }
```

In short, I'd like to `runCalculation` on every combination of parameters.  `runCalculation` returns a `ResultObject`.  I'd like to return *the* `ResultObject` that returns the maximum `ResultObject.getValue()`.

Ideally, I would like to use `parallel()` to run this as quickly as possible.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a little class to wrap each calculation

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxParameterValue = 10;

        Set<Integer> params = IntStream.range(0, maxParameterValue).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Result bestResult = Sets.cartesianProduct(params, params, params).stream()
                .parallel()
                .map(Result::new)
                .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Result::getResult)).get();

        System.out.println(bestResult);
    }

    private static double runCalculation(int a, int b, int c) {
        // This just sums the 3 inputs replace with your function
        return a + b + c;
    }

    private static class Result {
        int a,b, c;
        double result;

        public Result(List<Integer> params) {
            this.a = params.get(0);
            this.b = params.get(1);
            this.c = params.get(2);
            this.result = runCalculation(a, b, c);
        }

        public double getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Result{a=%d, b=%d, c=%d, result=%s}", a, b, c, result);
        }
    }
}
```

it uses Guava to generate the parameters

Answer (score 1):

It takes a few `flatMap` operations, but the following is the result:

```java
public ResultObject getBestObjectWithParameters() {
    int maxParameterValue = 10;
    return IntStream.range(0, maxParameterValue)
            .mapToObj(a -> a) // Stream<Integer>
            .flatMap(a -> IntStream.range(0, maxParameterValue)
                    .mapToObj(b -> b) // Stream<Integer>
                    .flatMap(b -> IntStream.range(0, maxParameterValue)
                            .mapToObj(c -> c) // Stream<Integer>
                            .map(c -> runCalculation(a, b, c)) // Stream<ResultObject>
                     ) // Stream<resultObject>
            ) // Stream<ResultObject>
            .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(ResultObject::getValue))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Note that I have to use `mapToObj`, because `IntStream` can only `flatMap` to an `IntStream`, not to a `Stream<ResultObject>`.

Comment: I forgot about `.boxed()`, that's of course better than those `.mapToObj` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IntStream` and `flatMap`, as in:

```
  int maxParameterValue = 10;
          IntStream.range(0, maxParameterValue).boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, maxParameterValue).boxed()
                .flatMap(j -> IntStream.range(0, maxParameterValue).boxed()
                    .map(k -> i + "-" + j + "-" + k)))
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

BTW, this was much more painful to write than it needed to be. Streams are nice, but other languages would make this so much more concise and not require the annoying `.boxed()` stuff.